# Validating mutually exclusive elements in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dict that can have three keys `url`. `link` and `path`. These three need to be mutually exclusive when I'm validating the dict i.e. If the key `url` exists in the dict then `path` and `link` can't exist and so on...

To add to the complication: The main key cant be empty (null or '')

I've often come across scenarios like this and wrote a bunch of conditional statements to test this. Is there a better way?

Thanks.

Comment: Why use three keys if you can never have all three set at once? Why not just use one, and then have use an array or another key to define if it is an url, a link, or a path?

Comment: That would work. This is for my Django web app that gets these as URL params when our customer makes a request from the JS. I don't have access to the JS so I cant modify it and therefore I'm stuck with this situation. :(

Answer (score 4):

To test your condition, you could do something like this:

```
# d is your dict
has_url  = bool(d.get('url',  False))
has_link = bool(d.get('link', False))
has_path = bool(d.get('path', False))
# ^ is XOR
if not (has_url ^ has_link ^ has_path):
    # either none of them are present, or there is more than one, or the
    # one present is empty or None
```

To find which one is present, and act on it, you probably still need three separate branches, though.

Comment: This will be problematic if `d[url] = False`. In this case, `d.get(url)` will return `False` and you have no way of telling why

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Well, it's an URL, supposedly. It doesn't make sense for it to be a boolean, now does it.

Comment: True, but it doesn't hurt to make sure (esp. since it's not specified in the problem statement). Also, not making that assumption makes the code more robust

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Your code fails to check the second condition though (not None or ''). And to do that without coercing to bool requires a fairly lengthy expression for each.

Answer (score 1):

+1 to CatPlusPlus, but there's an issue in his code that I have commented on, but here's the fix:

```
if (url in d and d[url] not in [None, '']) ^ (link in d and d[link] not in [None, '']) ^ (path in d and d[path] not in [None, '']):
    # mutex condition satisfied
else:
    # at least two are keys in the dict or none are
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you shouldn't be using a dictionary, but rather a tuple:

```
(value, "url") or (value, "path") or (value, "link")
```